# Is this a good way to use static_cast<void>(0) for nothing?

Tags: c++, c++17, parasoft

Imagine that we do not have the `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute in C++.

How we could use this ability **before inventing this attribute** (I mean, before C++17)?

I found one solution:

```
static_cast<void>(0)
```

But I'm not sure that is correct! Can you explain a better solution (doesn't show compiler warnings, and passes static code analyzer)?

Edit:
I wrote just one example of casting to void (maybe_unused was one , and below is another and etc ...) :

```cpp
obj.enabled() ? static_cast<void>(0) : obj.DoThat(); /*as title said doing nothing*/
```

so I mean static_cast(variable) too.

Comment: Presumably instead of `0` you'd write the unused variable? Then yes, this is probably the best solution, ignoring `[[maybe_unused]]`. Though more often I see it with a less verbose C-style cast.

Comment: if you're refer to the function parameter, you can also remove the name.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> static_cast<void>(0)
> ```
>
> But I'm not sure that is correct!

`static_cast<void>(0)` doesn't make much sense, but I presume you mean `static_cast<void>(maybe_unused_variable);`

It is correct in the sense that it is well-formed. The standard doesn't specify when a compiler will warn about unused variables (except for recommending that `[[maybe_unused]]` suppresses such warning), but a cast to void is a de-facto convention to signify potentially unused names.

> Can you explain a better solution

As suggested by [Human-Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71414903/is-this-a-good-way-to-use-static-castvoid0-for-nothing/71415056?noredirect=1#comment126229878_71415056) and originally by [Herb Sutter](https://herbsutter.com/2009/10/18/mailbag-shutting-up-compiler-warnings/), you could call an empty function template:

```
template <typename T>
void unused(const T&){}

// usage
unused(maybe_unused_variable);
```

Comment: You could mention that function parameters do not need names, so a (definitely) unused parameter can be declared as `void foo(int)` or `void foo(int /*unused*/)`. IMO it's better way than a macro, which someone might try to use in parameter list (where `[[maybe_unuesed]]` would go).

Comment: I prefer Herb Sutter's proposal of just [using a function template without an argument](https://herbsutter.com/2009/10/18/mailbag-shutting-up-compiler-warnings/) over a macro-based approach, like `template <typename T> void unused(const T&){}`. If you make it variadic like `template <typename...Ts> void unused(const Ts&...){}`, then it scales to work with other variadic arguments too (`unused(args...)`)

Comment: @Human-Compiler Oh yea. That's much better.